# Error: That model does not exist (OpenAI)

Tags: openai-api, gpt-3

When using a model I fine-tuned for GPT-3 using `openai api` from CLI, it stopped working and I get an error with this message: "That model does not exist".

But this is a model I have used before, so it should exist.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes with new versions old fine-tuned stop working.

To check out current fine tuned models besides running `openai api fine_tunes.list` you should check the fine-tuned model showing up in Playground with the other models.

Comment: how do i install this command?

Comment: `pip install --upgrade openai`

source: https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning